# Removing Tab bar on Push view

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

i have added tab bar in app delegate. When i pushed the view from one of my view te tab bar got removed. I want that tab bar on pushed view also.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    AudioViewController * audioViewController = [[AudioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AudioViewController" bundle:nil];
    audioViewController.title = @"audio";
    audioViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"audio 30x30.png"];

    ViewController *videoViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    videoViewController.title = @"video";
    videoViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"video 30x30.png"];   

    ViewController *aboutViewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    aboutViewController.title = @"about";
    aboutViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"about1_iPhone.png"];

    ViewController *infoViewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    infoViewController.title = @"info";
    infoViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"info 30x30.png"];

    PlaylistViewController *PlaylistViewControllerObj = [[PlaylistViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlaylistViewController" bundle:nil];
    PlaylistViewControllerObj.title = @"Playlist";
    PlaylistViewControllerObj.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ko.png"];

    NSArray *viewControllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:audioViewController,videoViewController,aboutViewController,infoViewController,PlaylistViewControllerObj,nil];

    UITabBarController * myTabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [myTabbarController setViewControllers:viewControllerArray];
    navigationControllerObj = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myTabbarController];
    [navigationControllerObj setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
    self.window.rootViewController =navigationControllerObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2, *viewController3 , *viewController4 , *viewController5 ;

```
viewController1 = [[Homeviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController2 = [[NearbyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController3 = [[SearchViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController4 = [[FavoritiesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController5 = [[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

 UINavigationController *homeNavi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

 UINavigationController *SearchNavi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController3];

 UINavigationController *NearbyNavi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController2];

 UINavigationController *FavNavi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController4];

 UINavigationController *MoreNavi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController5];

 TabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

 TabbarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavi,SearchNavi,NearbyNavi,FavNavi,MoreNavi, nil];



[self presentModalViewController:TabbarController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

AudioViewController * audioViewController = [[AudioViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AudioViewController" bundle:nil];
audioViewController.title = @"audio";
audioViewController.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"audio 30x30.png"];


UINavigationController *navaudioViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:audioViewController];

PlaylistViewController *PlaylistViewControllerObj = [[PlaylistViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PlaylistViewController" bundle:nil];
PlaylistViewControllerObj.title = @"Playlist";
PlaylistViewControllerObj.tabBarItem.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ko.png"];

UINavigationController *navPlaylistView = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:PlaylistViewControllerObj];

UITabBarController * myTabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
myTabbarController.viewControllers = @[navHomeController,navPlaylistView];
self.window.rootViewController = myTabbarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check value of this property in the `UIViewController` you are pushing

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code

call this method , where to present UITabBar

In .h,

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigation;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UITabBarController *tabbarcontroller;

In .m,

-(void)loadtabview
{

```
self.tabbarcontroller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];
self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"firstViewController" bundle:nil];
navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.firstViewController];
self.viewController.navigationItem.title=@"First";
[localControllersArray addObject:navigation];


self.secondViewController = [[secondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
self.secondViewController.navigationItem.title=@"second";
[localControllersArray addObject:navigation];


self.ThirdViewController = [[Third ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Third ViewController" bundle:nil];
navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ThirdViewController];
self.secondViewController.navigationItem.title=@"Third";
[localControllersArray addObject:navigation];

tabbarcontroller.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
self.tabbarcontroller.delegate = self;
[self.tabbarcontroller setSelectedIndex:0];
[self.window addSubview:tabbarcontroller.view];
```

}