# Tab bar moves away from screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

My Tab bar should stay on screen when I click on **button** in **Test2 View Controller**.

I've set **Test 3 View Controller's** Bottom bar to **inferred** and tried **Translucent tab bar**. I've changed the segue from **push** to **modal**. I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158537/removing-tab-bar-on-push-view), but doesn't work for iOS7.

**TestTabBarController.m** this doesn't work either:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    Test3ViewController * viewController1 = [[Test3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *homeNavi=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
    self.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavi, nil];    
}
```

This also doesn't work:

```
- (IBAction)buttonpress:(id)sender {      
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard   storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];       
   Test3ViewController * test3ViewController = (Test3ViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test3View"];     
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:test3ViewController animated:YES]; 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: Add a Navigation controller between Test Tab Bar Controller and Test2 View Controller.

Answer (score 1):

First: 
Your link `Test2` to `Test3` in `storyboard` is `Modal`,
change it to `Push`:
[image]

And u'll see your navigation bar.

Second:
Don't use the `segue` mechanism for your task.
Use the `pushViewController` on `UINavigationController`

Comment: This doesnt' work:
`- (IBAction)buttonpress:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    Test3ViewController * test3ViewController = (Test3ViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"test3View"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test3ViewController animated:YES];
}`

Answer (score 0):

A modal view will cover the tab bar. If you want to load a view after you hit the 'Button' do the following:

```
- (IBAction) loadNewView:(id) sender {
    Test3ViewController * viewController1 = [[Test3ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController1 animated:YES];
}
```

Then link that up with your button...

Comment: This doesn't work: pushing a navigation controller is not supported.